# Convert json with children to dataframe in R

Tags: json, r

I have json with children as follows:

```
{
"name": "Steve", "imageURL":"blah","id":"1",
"children": [

             {"name": "Melissa", "imageURL":"blah","id":"2",
             "children":[{"name": "Chris", "imageURL":"blah","id":"3"},
                         {"name": "Robert", "imageURL":"blah","id":"4"}]},

             {"name": "Joker", "imageURL":"blah","id":"5",
             "children":[{"Precilla": "word 1", "imageURL":"blah","id":"6"},
                         {"Gal": "word 8", "imageURL":"blah","id":"7"}]},

             {"name": "Seven", "imageURL":"blah","id":"8",
             "children":[{"Janeway": "word 1", "imageURL":"blah","id":"9"},
                         {"Nelix": "word 8", "imageURL":"blah","id":"10"}]}

             ]
}
```

I need to represent this in R as a data frame with the same hierarchical information.  I need to later export this as the same JSON from R.

I have tried starting from the data frames as shown in other answers that discuss moving from data frames in R to JSON with children but it does not give the correct structure.

Comment: So what format do you want the result in?

Comment: something that RJSONIO can output as the JSON shown above using toJSON. In other words, what would the data frame have to look like for RJSONIO to produce that JSON shown.

Comment: perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339805/converting-json-format-to-csv-to-upload-data-table-in-r-to-produce-d3-bubble-cha/31352770#31352770 will help