# Converting JSON format to CSV to upload data table in R to produce D3 bubble chart

Tags: javascript, json, r, csv, d3.js

I am trying to use the [D3 Bubble Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) in R to make my own bubbles chart with grouped bubble colours.

I have upload the *index.html* and the *flare.json files* from the D3 into R and it produced the bubble chart when run. But I didn't wanted to manually change this JSON code to create my own bubbles and groups (header below shows a set of 3 bubble groups with names for the different groups).

```
    {
     "name": "flare",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "analytics",
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "cluster",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
          {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
          {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
          {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "graph",
         "children": [
          {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
          {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
          {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
          {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
          {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "optimization",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
         ]
        }
       ]
```

Using the **jsonlite** package (which from reading online can handle more complex json structures) I have converted to a dataframe.

```
 library(jsonlite)
 fromJSON("flare.json",simplifyDateframe = FALSE)
```

This is **without** the dataframe structure requested (example).

```
$children[[10]]$children[[6]]$children[[10]]
$children[[10]]$children[[6]]$children[[10]]$name
[1] "OperatorSwitch"

$children[[10]]$children[[6]]$children[[10]]$size
[1] 2581
```

This is **with** the dataframe structure requested (example).

```
 fromJSON("flare.json",simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
```

However it produces a **long concatenated list of data** which I have been trying to untangle to automate with my data.

```
Arrays, Colors, Dates, Displays, Filter, Geometry, heap, IEvaluable,  IPredicate, IValueProxy, math, Maths, Orientation, palette, Property, Shapes, Sort, Stats, Strings, 8258, 10001, 8217, 12555, 2324, 10993, NA, 335, 383, 874, NA, 17705, 1486, NA, 5559, 19118, 6887, 6557, 22026, FibonacciHeap, HeapNode, 9354, 1233, DenseMatrix, IMatrix, SparseMatrix, 3165, 2815, 3366, ColorPalette, Palette, ShapePalette, SizePalette, 6367, 1229, 2059, 2291
```

*Suggested solutions ...*

*FOR LOOPS (Time-restricted)*

I have thought about writing multiple for loops to re-construct the JSON nest structure (which I am stronger at but I have a deadline and this may take a while). But I thought that someone who is more JSON savy might be able to help.

*CSV CONVERTED FORMAT (doesn't work)*

I also attempted to converted the flare.json file  using [JSON to CSV](https://json-csv.com/) convertor to produce the CSV format needed to test whether I could update the content from the CSV directly to R but that didn't work (even with the addition of the flare.json header content that isn't automate from the jsonlite toJSON).

### What I really need

A solution for converting the flare.json from **JSON into a dataframe or table** so I can upload my data with names, sizes and groups to  **convert back to JSON** to produce my own bubble chart?

If possible it would be great to achieve this all in R, which I don't think is impossible but am happy to hear other suggestions.

I am quite stumped as what to do next. I normally deal with matrices in R so dealing with JSON lists and array is not my strong point.

Comment: I guess one initial question is "what would you envision the structure of the data frame to be"? There is a blog post on going from a data frame _to_ the "flare" format - http://quantifyingmemory.blogspot.com/2013/11/d3-without-javascript.html - but I'm not sure if that's the data frame structure you're expecting to be able to work with.

Comment: These hairy beasts can be difficult at first, but you'll be whizzing through them easily in no time.  If it is ok, can we step back just a little more?  While recreating the bl.ocks example with flare.json is interesting, what is your expected use case?  What will be the source data in R (edge list, adjacency matrix, data.frame) that you would like to plug into the circle-packed chart?  I'm thinking we just make a htmlwidget out of this to solve all our problems :)

For now, I'll work on some examples of json -> R -> json pipeline with flare.json.

Comment: (this is going to be an interesting SO thread :-)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks that link is useful. I suppose its less about the nodes but more about the grouping.

Comment: @timelyportfolio So here is my user case. I want to represent data size from different data sources. So for example I have social media followers (Facebook 10,000, Twitter 5000, Youtube 200) that is one group and another group could be Web Views (Website 10000, Secondary Website 2500). Then those 2 groups are online data so are grouped. So I really want a table where I can put the data source name (Facebook), size (10,000), primary group (Social Media), overall group (Online) to then be transformed into the right JSON format like flare in R?

Comment: well, in this case if I understand correctly, unless you need a nested hierarchy, we can just use a `data.frame` or `vector`.  I'll post in an answer below.

Answer (score 5):

This might provide us something else to think about.  I'll put comments inline in the code.  You can see a [live example](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/d3c478944fa7ccecf262).

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)


flare_json <- rjson::fromJSON(  ## rjson just works better on these for me
    file = "http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063269/flare.json"
)

# let's have a look at the structure of flare.json
# listviewer htmlwidget might help us see what is happening
#   devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/listviewer")
#   library(listviewer)
jsonedit(
  paste0(
    readLines("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063269/flare.json")
    ,collapse=""
  )
)

# the interesting thing about Mike Bostock's Bubble Chart example
#   though is that the example removes the nested hierarchy
#    with a JavaScript function called classes
#// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
#function classes(root) {
#  var classes = [];
#  
#  function recurse(name, node) {
#    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
#    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
#  }
#  
#  recurse(null, root);
#  return {children: classes};
#}

# let's try to recreate this in R
classes <- function(root){
  classes <- data.frame()

  haschild <- function(node){
    (!is.null(node) && "children" %in% names(node))
  }

  recurse <- function(name,node){
    if(haschild(node)){
      lapply(
        1:length(node$children)
        ,function(n){
          recurse(node$name,node$children[[n]])
        }
      )
    } else {
      classes <<- bind_rows(
        classes,
        data.frame(
          "packageName"= name
          ,"className" = node[["name"]]
          ,"size" = node[["size"]]
          ,stringsAsFactors = F
        )
      )
    }
  }

  recurse(root$name,root)
  return(classes)
}

# now with a R flavor our class replica should work
flare_df <- classes(flare_json)


# so the example uses a data.frame with columns
#   packageName, className, size
# and feeds that to bubble.nodes where bubble = d3.layout.pack
# fortunately Joe Cheng has already made a htmlwidget called bubbles
#   https://github.com/jcheng5/bubbles
# that will produce a d3.layout.pack bubble chart

library(scales)

bubbles(
  flare_df$size
  ,flare_df$className
  ,color = col_factor(
    RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(9,"Set1")
    ,factor(flare_df$packageName)
  )(flare_df$packageName)
  ,height = 600
  ,width = 960
)

# it's not perfect with things such as text sizing
#    but it's a start
```

If you still think you want a nested d3 JSON hierarchy, here is some code.

```
#  convert this to nested d3 json format
#    this is example data provided in a comment to this post
df <- data.frame(
  "overallgroup" = "Online"
  ,"primarygroup" = c(rep("Social Media",3),rep("Web",2))
  ,"datasource" = c("Facebook","Twitter","Youtube","Website","Secondary Website")
  ,"size" = c(10000,5000,200,10000,2500)
  ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# recommend using data.tree to ease our pain here
#devtools::install_github("gluc/data.tree")
library(data.tree)

# the much easier way
df$pathString <- apply(df[,1:3],MARGIN=1, function(x){paste0(x,collapse="/")})
root <- as.Node(df[,4:5])    

# the harder manual way
root <- Node$new("root")
sapply(unique(df[,1]),root$AddChild)
apply(
  df[,1:ncol(df)]
  ,MARGIN = 1
  ,function(row){
    lapply(2:length(row),function(cellnum){
      cell <- row[cellnum]
      if( cellnum < ncol(df) ){ # assume last column is attribute
        parent <- Reduce(function(x,y){x$Climb(y)},as.character(row[1:(cellnum-1)]),root)
        if(is.null(parent$Climb(cell))){
          cellnode <- parent$AddChild( cell )
        }  
      } else{
        cellnode <- Reduce(function(x,y){x$Climb(y)},as.character(row[1:(cellnum-1)]),root)
        cellnode$Set( size = as.numeric(cell) )
      }
    })
  }
)


# now we should be able to supply root to networkD3
#   that expects a typical d3 nested JSON
#devtools::install_github("christophergandrud/networkD3")
library(networkD3)
treeNetwork( root$ToList(unname=TRUE) )

# or to get it in JSON
jsonlite::toJSON( root$ToList(unname=TRUE), auto_unbox=TRUE)
```

Comment: two other examples of converting R data structures to the nested d3 format

`data.tree`

https://github.com/gluc/data.tree/blob/master/R/node_conversion.R#L73-L133


`networkD3`

https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/blob/master/R/treeNetwork.R#L143-L190

Comment: I had to used the bubbles widget for this deadline but had to remove the text as it was unreadable and didn't orientate text with the bubble. This widget hasn't been worked on in 6 months not sure what development plans there are. So I still need to get the convert table of flare back into the json format to use in index like flare.JSON ->Table.csv->newdata.JSON -> new data bubbles using index.html

Comment: any way we can ignore flare from now on and use real/sample data, since flare is not the data that you expect to use?  Do you still anticipate starting in JSON?  It is very easy to start in R with a R structure and convert at the end.

Comment: d3plus has lots of examples http://d3plus.org/examples/ ; there is an htmlwidget started for that https://github.com/jpmarindiaz/d3plus but it still requires some work.

Comment: the view of JSON using the edit widget is great trick!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Posting this only for further discussion. As @timelyportfolio said, there's quite a bit to consider. Here's one path (only going from "flare" JSON to a long data frame for now until we get more of what you're looking for).

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

flare <- fromJSON("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063269/flare.json",
                          simplifyVector=FALSE)

flare_df <- bind_rows(lapply(flare$children,
    function(x) {
      kids <- as.list(x)
      kids$stringsAsFactors=FALSE # prevents bind_rows warnings
      do.call("data.frame", kids)
    }
)) %>% gather(child_path, value, -name)

set.seed(1492) # results reproducibility
print(flare_df[sample(nrow(flare_df), 50),])

## Source: local data frame [50 x 3]
## 
##       name                         child_path value
## 1  display                   children.name.18    NA
## 2     util                   children.size.11  5559
## 3  display                    children.name.9    NA
## 4  display           children.children.size.9    NA
## 5  physics           children.children.name.4    NA
## 6    query             children.children.name   add
## 7  physics children.children.children.size.22    NA
## 8     data                   children.name.20    NA
## 9      vis          children.children.size.20 19382
## 10    flex          children.children.name.36    NA
## ..     ...                                ...   ...

# just showing the top-level nodes are present for an example

select(flare_df, name) %>% arrange(name) %>% distinct %>% print(n=1000)

## Source: local data frame [10 x 1]
## 
##         name
## 1  analytics
## 2    animate
## 3       data
## 4    display
## 5       flex
## 6    physics
## 7      query
## 8      scale
## 9       util
## 10       vis
```

Unwrapping that for data frame to "flare" is pretty straightforward, but that may not be a usable data frame format for your manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @timelyportfolio for pointing me to this. You can achieve conversion from and to data.frame / json quite simply with the data.tree package (latest from github required). The trick is to paste together a path:

```
#devtools::install_github("gluc/data.tree")
libraray(data.tree)

df <- data.frame(
  "overallgroup" = "Online"
  ,"primarygroup" = c(rep("Social Media",3),rep("Web",2))
  ,"datasource" = c("Facebook","Twitter","Youtube","Website","Secondary Website")
  ,"size" = c(10000,5000,200,10000,2500)
  ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


df$pathString <- paste("root", df$overallgroup, df$primarygroup, df$datasource, sep="/")
root <- as.Node(df[,-c(1, 2, 3)])

# now we should be able to supply root to networkD3
#   that expects a typical d3 nested JSON
#devtools::install_github("christophergandrud/networkD3")
library(networkD3)
treeNetwork( root$ToList(unname=TRUE) )

# or to get it in JSON
jsonlite::toJSON( root$ToList(unname=TRUE), auto_unbox=TRUE)
```