# How do I generate multilevel JSON with R?

Tags: python, json, r

I want to create a [treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) using a JSON file that I output from R (or Python, I could switch over to Python if I really can't do this in R?). The 
data looks something like [this](http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/csv-json/data/religions.csv):

```
cat type    pop
Buddhism    Other   116237936
Christianity    Anglican    36955033
Christianity    Catholic    391332035
Christianity    Orthodox    98501171
Christianity    Other   13674466
Christianity    Mahayana    160887585
Islam   Ibadhi  62273219
Islam   Shia    19436742
Islam   Sunni   49050320
Judaism Conservative    1426350
Judaism Orthodox    856827
Judaism Other   7796835
Judaism Reform  1929388
```

And I need the json to look about like ...

```
  {"name": "Buddhism",
   "children": 
        {"name": "Other", "size": 116237936}
    },
    {
     "name": "Christianity",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Anglican", "size": 36955033},
      {"name": "Catholic", "size": 391332035},
      {"name": "Orthodox", "size": 98501171},
      {"name": "Other", "size": 13674466},
      {"name": "Mahayana", "size": 160887585}
     ]
    } ...
```

I looked at the documentation for [rjson](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) and [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/) and neither seems to make it seem straightforward.

Comment: perhaps this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339805/converting-json-format-to-csv-to-upload-data-table-in-r-to-produce-d3-bubble-cha/31352770#31352770 will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do the job? `Split` the dataframe on the column `cat`, then drop the first column from each resulting dataframe and convert to JSON using `toJSON` from the `jsonlite` package.

```
JSONoutput <- jsonlite::toJSON(lapply(split(data, data$cat), function(x) {x[,-1]}))
```

Comment: That gets super close, though I now have  `{"Buddhism":[{"type":"Other","pop":116237936}]` and I need to coerce that into  `{"name": "Buddhism", "children":[{...}]`  Something to work from, though.

Comment: I think `JSONoutput <- jsonlite::toJSON(lapply(split(data, data$cat), function(x) {list("children"=x[,-1])}))`
 might do that for you.